# Monotouch supported architectures combo is disabled

Tags: xamarin.ios, app-store, application-loader

i use monotouch and try send my app to itunes with app loader 2.7

need change architecture in monotouch but

supported architectures combo is disabled in Iphone build options / Advanced.

I cant choose ARM7+ ARM6

i need help

Answer (score 1):

Set the deployment target (in the project options's iPhone Application tab) to something that runs an ARMv6 device (3.1 for instance).

If you for instance have deployment target set to 5.0, you don't need to include ARMv6 (since all devices that supports iOS 5.0 also supports ARMv7).